# Unite into one array based array from explode string in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a lot of array based explode a string like this :

```
$size = explode(",", $row->SIZE);
$coil_no = explode(",", $row->COIL_NO);
$net = explode(",", $row->NET);
$gross = explode(",", $row->GROSS);
$contract_no = explode(",", $row->CONTRACT_NO);
$location = explode(",", $row->LOCATION);
```

How can I unite those array into one multidimensional array ?

I have try like this :

```
foreach ($size as $value) {
            foreach ($coil_no as $coil) {
                $detail[] = array(
                    "coil_no" => $coil,
                    "size" => $value
                );
            }
        }
```

you know the result the looping is loop weird,
I need more elegant array, like

```
foreach ($unite_array as $row) :
    echo "<tr> $row->size </tr>" ;
endforeach;
```

What the best way to unite those array ?

Comment: I can't understand where the input is coming from or what shape it is in.  Is this coming from a loop of a mysqli resultset using fetch_object()?  Can you explain what your preferred multi-dimensional output is?  This page can better serve the public if you can clarify these points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own function which does the grouping on keys as required, see example below:

```
function array_group(){
    if(func_num_args() > 0) {
        $params = func_get_args();
        $result = array();
        foreach($params as $key => $param) {
            foreach($param['values'] as $k => $value) {
                $result[$k][$param['alias']] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}

$rows = array_group(
    array('alias' => 'size', 'values' => array(1,2,3,4,5)),
    array('alias' => 'coil_no', 'values' => array(6,7,8,9,10)),
    array('alias' => 'net', 'values' => array(11,12,13,14,15)),
    array('alias' => 'gross', 'values' => array(16,17,18,19,20)),
    array('alias' => 'contract_no', 'values' => array(21,22,23,24,25)),
    array('alias' => 'location', 'values' => array(26,27,28,29,30))
);
print_r($rows);
```

And you can access it like:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) :
    echo "<tr> {$row['size']} </tr>" ;
endforeach;
```